# How to create a folder on openshift for a site that allows users to upload images

Tags: postgresql, flask, openshift, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello and sorry (programming newbie here)! I am creating a site using Flask and SQLalchemy with postgresql where users can upload images. As of now, I'm stuck figuring out as to how to implement or create a folder within the openshift data dir which will store these uploaded images. Further, I am also figuring out as to how to direct these images to the folder created within openshift. I am tinkering with bits and scraps of codes that I have seen on the internet. Below is a code that I am using from an example online that is causing the problem when uploaded onto openshift.

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/static/img/'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    # Get the name of the uploaded file
    file = request.files['file']
    # Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        # Move the file form the temporal folder to
        # the upload folder we setup
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        # Redirect the user to the uploaded_file route, which
        # will basicaly show on the browser the uploaded file
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                filename=filename))

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

The site meets with an error locating the path to save the uploaded image (and hence calling it back to be displayed). I would also greatly appreciate if anybody can give any tips as to how I can implement some sort of relationship to link a user's account (whose data has been stored in a POSTgresql database) to the images that he has uploaded. Do try to avoid speaking in heavy coding jargon as I'm a self taught coding newbie. Thanks a million!

Respectfully,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you setup the upload path, but Openshift provides and environment variable for the data directory: `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`. Also you could just create a folder for each user's ID and store their pictures in their own folder. The data directory isn't scalable though, because it would only upload to the server your user hit and you would need to sync all of the data directories for each instance. Maybe think about using Amazon S3 or some other storage so that you can scale your Openshift app without worrying about scaling the uploads.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking through it. Yeah I have read it up somewhere that the upload path should be in that data directory. However  is it possible to create another folder within that "data dir folder" for better organisation. Also, since there can be an infinite number of users, I was thinking along the lines of appending the db with the uploaded image url which will have a relationship with the user's username. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes you can SSH into your instance and create a directory through the shell. The upload path should be the data directory because it won't be overwritten when you push new code. It is good for when you are just starting to test out your code, but Amazon S3 or some other storage will be better for production so you can setup your app to scale with load.

Comment: Ah ok ill try it out when i get back later and let you know how it goes. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You will want to set it equal to os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR']. And maybe append the subfolder you create in the directory to it.

Comment: Just change the top line in your code from the question so the app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] is equal to the path you want to the data directory. Once you SSH into your instance it is just a Linux shell. So you can run a normal mkdir command to create the folder.

Comment: If Im not mistaken, I should be definining this in the application file...? It should look something like uploads = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] + 'uploads'?

Comment: YEAH GOT IT TO WORK. Thank for being so patient! You really helped a lot (was stuck at this problem for weeks)!